# Initialize non existing keys to empty array list

Tags: gson

I have a class :

```
class Con {
 private List<Ind> inds;
}
```

I am using Gson in the usual way to convert a JSON string to this class object. so in case, the JSON doesn't have the key **inds** present this variable inds is assigned a null value. Is there a way to assign inds an empty ArrayList instead?
**My Thoughts:**
One straightforward way could be once the Gson object is built. Go over all the null objects and assign them to the new ArrayList<>(). Is there a better approach?

---

```
 public List<Ind> getInds() {
        return inds;
    }
```

Currently I am using the above getter in a code like :  con.getInds().stream() which is causing NullPointerException.
I am not sure what would be a good way to resolve this. Instead of List Should I return an Optional or Should I modify this getter like

```
   public List<Ind> getInds() {
            inds==null?new ArrayList<>():inds;
        }
```

The above will also resolve the NullPointerException. Not sure if there are pros and cons to using this approach. Although now there is no way to identify if the Json has a key with name inds or not. For the current code that I am writing this may not be required. But there is a meaning loss here certainly.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this would be to assign default values to the fields, for example:

```java
class Con {
    private List<Ind> inds = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Gson will keep this default value; only if the field is present in the JSON data it will reassign the field value.

There are however a few things to keep in mind:

- Your class needs a no-args constructor (implicit or explicit); otherwise Gson might [create instances without invoking the initializer blocks of the class](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#disableJdkUnsafe()), and therefore the field will be `null`
- If the field is present in JSON but has a JSON `null` value, then Gson will still set that as value
- You cannot tell afterwards whether the field was present in JSON but had an empty JSON array as value, or whether it was missing